# Populatie IN list with a subquery

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Preamble:
I'm working in an environment (Knowage) that let me only do `SELECT`s.
`$P{something}` is the call of a parameter replaced by knowage when running the query on the MSSQL engine

Whay I have to do:
I have to use a parameter to 'filter' the data with an entry that let take out all, currently I can only get filtered data, i cannot take out 'all'

My query looks like this:

```
select ClusterDRG, t.N as N_cur, u.N as N_pas, t.SubStabilimento
from(  
--- prendo i primi 10 DRG del periodo in corso  confrontando i valori degli stessi DRG del periodo precedente (indipendentemente dal fatto che fossero o meno tra i primi 10)
SELECT count(ProgrSdo) as N
      ,ClusterDRG, TipologiaDRG as tipodrg
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY anno,tipologiaDRG ORDER BY count(progrsdo) desC) as Ordine
     , case when [Anno]=$P{lista_anni} then 'Attuale' 
            when [Anno]=$P{lista_anni}-1 then 'Precedente' 
            else cast([Anno] as varchar (4)) end as Anno
  FROM 
  MY_TABLE

  where left(Mese,2) <=$P{lista_mesi}
  and ANNO = $P{lista_anni} -- l'anno corrente 
  and SubStabilimento = $P{lista_stabilimenti} -- here is my issue
  and codicepresidio=111111

  group by ClusterDRG, TipologiaDRG, anno, SubStabilimento
  ) t
  left join 
  (
  SELECT count(ProgrSdo) as N
      ,ClusterDRG, TipologiaDRG as tipodrg

     , case when [Anno]=$P{lista_anni} then 'Attuale' 
            when [Anno]=$P{lista_anni}-1 then 'Precedente'
    else cast([Anno] as varchar (4)) end as Anno
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY anno,tipologiaDRG ORDER BY count(progrsdo) desC) as Ordine
  FROM  MY_TABLE
  where left(Mese,2) <= $P{lista_mesi} 
  and ANNO = $P{lista_anni}-1 -- l'anno passato 

  and codicepresidio=111111


    and SubStabilimento = $P{lista_stabilimenti} -- here is my issue
    group by ClusterDRG, TipologiaDRG, anno, SubStabilimento
  )u on t.ClusterDRG=u.ClusterDRG and t.TipoDRG=u.TipoDRG and t.SubStabilimento=u.SubStabilimento
```

my parameters got these values:

```
$P{lista_mesi} := 5
$P{lista_anni} := 2018
$P{lista_stabilimenti} := **here is my issue**
```

I want to use `$P{lista_stabilimenti}` to filter by single entity (and at doing that now it works) or all if a specific value is set.

so If I have `$P{lista_stabilimenti} := 'stab1'`
I get

```
clust1, 123, 122, stab1
clust2, 789, 456, stab1
```

and If I have `$P{lista_stabilimenti} := 'ALL'` (This is the behaviour I'm trying to make)
I get

```
clust1, 123, 122, stab1
clust2, 789, 456, stab1
clust1, 321, 221, stab2
clust2, 987, 654, stab2
clust5, 963, 258, stab3
```

I tryed  populating the and `SubStabilimento = $P{lista_stabilimenti}`
as

```
[...]
and SubStabilimento in ( case when exists ( select  SubStabilimento from Knowage_L15_COLLEGATA where SubStabilimento = $P{lista_stabilimenti}) then  $P{lista_stabilimenti}
                             when $P{lista_stabilimenti} like 'TUTTI' then (

                             select  STUFF( 
                                (
                                 SELECT ',' + SubStabilimento 
                                 FROM  MY_TABLE v
                                 where CodicePresidio = '111111'
                                 group by SubStabilimento
                                 FOR XML PATH('')
                                ), 
                            1, 1, '') 

                            )
                            end)
[...]
```

With this I get a string like stab1,stab2,stab3 but I'm not able to feed it to the IN clause

Answer (score 0):

A pizza made my brain to grind again, my solution is *like* this:

```
[...]
and SubStabilimento LIKE ( select case when exists ( 
                                                select  SubStabilimento 
                                                from MY_TABLE
                                                where SubStabilimento = $P{lista_stabilimenti}) 
                                              then  $P{lista_stabilimenti}

                                        when $P{lista_stabilimenti} like 'TUTTI'
                                              then '%'  end    as SubStab )
[...]
```